# Libgdx - preformance tweaks

Tags: android, libgdx

Every game needs to be optimized. So, here are my next questions.

I have 4 screens a Menu, a Shop, a Game Screen and a Game Over Screen. And each one loads a ton of textures. Should I instead make 4 texture atlases, 1 for each screen, and pack the textures accordingly. Is there alot of perfomance gain?

Also should I pass the screens around instead of disposing them and creating them again each time? If I reuse them I'm gonna be using more ram, so any thoughts?

I get currenty a pixmap already disposed error that has something to do with free type font. So I am intending to save free type font into Asset Manager, I didn't do it before because it didn't work. Is there a special way to save the generator font?

Comment: Are you trying to get the screens to load faster? Or have higher FPS?

ps: if you are using multiple different fonts (or sizes) and want memory performance gain, look into distance field font.

Comment: Ye when I change screens I make the transparency go to 0 and then to 1, and it lagged alot, then I made an if (delta < 0.04), so that it would skip the first few frames, now it looks smooth, but I want it even better. I am only using 1 font and 1 size so what would be the best way to save it?

Comment: 1 font 1 size would be best to just generate a bitmap font and put that in your atlas. Lag is usually caused by creating new objects or loading big or a lot of textures. So if you just load them beforehand and create your objects during some loading screen you will have significantly less lag

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to just keep a reference to each screen than? Because screen's creation of object is mostly it. Textures are already loaded in Asset Manager. Btw. what else way could I save my free type font instead of using a atlas, any other suggestions? I'm asking these because I will follow the tips for my next game. But in here if I just save a generator, it doesn't work...

Comment: I would personally not recommend using freetype, just bitmap fonts. But it's obviously up to you. I personally use a screenManager that has references for all screens which I initialize in thread during a splash screen (along with asset loading using the asset manager update function). So in short: Yes. keep references for screens and their objects. because they don't really use that much memory anyway.

Comment: Wait, how can I then get my own words style, if I only use bitmap fonts? Isn't the point of free type font to generate your own font style? I need a style that fits into my game!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your own style" but you can create a bitmap font of any font you would want in your game. It's just that you generate the glyphs beforehand in stead of during load.

Comment: What is the difference between free type and bitmap font? Well I give a free type reference to a bitmap font. So in the end both use a bitmap font. So why is then free type used?

Comment: freetype can be used to generate bitmap fonts on the fly, which means if you use many different sizes, your app is smaller (less asset size)

Comment: ye but the thing is I'm looking for BankGothic Md BT Medium, and there are only ttf files, can't seem to find a .fnt file. Of course I would also need a size 40. I'm hoping I will get rid of the pixmap disposed problem.

Comment: you can generate bitmap fonts yourself using tools like hiero or bmfont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing, since you posted no code, but this is generally what I do in my games:

```
public MainGame extends Game{
    MenuScreen     menu;
    ShopScreen     shop;
    GameScreen     game;
    GameOverScreen gameOver;

    public void create(){
        menu     = new MenuScreen(this);
        shop     = new ShopScreen(this);
        game     = new GameScreen(this);
        gameOver = new GameOverScreen(this);

        this.setScreen(menu);
    }

    public void render(){
        super.render();
    }

    public void dispose(){
        menu.dispose();
        shop.dispose();
        game.dispose();
        gameOver.dispose();
    }
}
```

And in each screens, the constructor looks like this:

```
MainGame game;

public GameScreen(MainGame game){
    this.game = game;
}
```

So that no matter where in the screens, I can do this:

```
game.setScreen(game.gameOver);
```

As for your textures, I would not know. I never have used many textures in one game, but I would assume that minimizing the amount of textures would make the game run faster. Think about it, if you have many textures, the game has to go through ever single one of those textures, and render every single one, every render method call. Making it a smaller number would reduce the amount of pictures needed to be rendered every single render method call.